# forward + displacement

Tags: python, quantlib

I I am trying to price a cap/floor using Quantlib in Python.
the initial code from from this website:
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/interest-rate-cap-floor-valuation-quantlib-python.html

Here is my code to price a floor on EURIBOR1M.

When I print the results , I get the following error:

RuntimeError: forward + displacement (-0.437337 + 0) must be positive

And when I launch the computation for a floor I get this error:

```
start_date = ql.Date(4, 2, 2019)
end_date = ql.Date(31, 8 , 2023)
period = ql.Period(1, ql.Months)
calendar = ql.TARGET()
buss_convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
rule = ql.DateGeneration.Forward
end_of_month = False

schedule = ql.Schedule(start_date, end_date, period,
                       calendar, buss_convention, buss_convention, 
                       rule, end_of_month)

ibor_index = ql.Euribor(ql.Period(1, ql.Months), ts_handle)
ibor_index.addFixing(ql.Date(31,1, 2019), -0.368)
ibor_leg = ql.IborLeg([2074408.03], schedule, ibor_index)

strike = 0.0
floor = ql.Floor(ibor_leg, [strike])

vols = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.547295))
engine2 = ql.BlackCapFloorEngine(ts_handle, ovs_handle)
floor.setPricingEngine(engine2)
print (floor.NPV())
```

RuntimeError: forward + displacement (-0.368 + 0) must be positive

```
 import QuantLib as ql
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    %matplotlib inline

calc_date = ql.Date(22, 2, 2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

dates = [ql.Date(22,2,2019), ql.Date(22,4,2019), 
         ql.Date(23,5,2019), ql.Date(24,6,2019),
         ql.Date(24,7,2019), ql.Date(22,8,2019),
         ql.Date(23,9,2019), ql.Date(23,10,2019),
         ql.Date(22,11,2019), ql.Date(23,12,2019),
         ql.Date(23,1,2020), ql.Date(24,2,2020),
         ql.Date(22,5,2020), ql.Date(24,8,2020),
         ql.Date(23,11,2020), ql.Date(22,2,2021),
         ql.Date(24,2,2022), ql.Date(23,2,2023),
         ql.Date(22,2,2024), ql.Date(24,2,2025),
         ql.Date(23,2,2026), ql.Date(22,2,2027), 
         ql.Date(24,2,2028), ql.Date(22,2,2029),
         ql.Date(24,2,2031), ql.Date(23,2,2034), 
         ql.Date(24,2,2039), ql.Date(22,2,2044),
         ql.Date(22,2,2049), 
         ]

yields = [-0.36800000,-0.36500000,
          -0.36520000,-0.36430000,
          -0.36350000,-0.36200000,
          -0.36190000,-0.36150000,
          -0.36000000,-0.35890000,
          -0.35680000,-0.35410000,
          -0.34600000,-0.33650000,
          -0.32000000,-0.30490000,
          -0.22600000,-0.13200000,
          -0.02640000,0.08200000,
          0.19150000,0.30100000,
          0.40100000,0.49900000,
          0.68700000,0.89380000,
          1.06480000,1.13200000,
          1.14900000]


day_count = ql.ActualActual()
calendar = ql.TARGET()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compounding_frequency = ql.Annual

term_structure = ql.ZeroCurve(dates, yields, day_count, calendar, 
                       interpolation, compounding, compounding_frequency)
ts_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(term_structure)
ts_handle.referenceDate()

strikes = [0.01,0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
expiries = [ql.Period(i, ql.Years) for i in range(1,6)]
vols = ql.Matrix(len(expiries), len(strikes))
data = [
        [90.635, 96.25, 73.745, 67.215, 61.17],#vector of vols by strike
        [66.665, 70.58, 60.48,  55.18,  49.6],
        [61.225, 64.64, 56.595, 55.18, 49.6],
        [57.25,  60.33, 53.5695, 49.045, 43.695],
        [51.645, 54.29, 49.065,  45.015, 39.915],
        [47.755,50.13,  45.8,    42.04,  37.21]
   ]

for i in range(vols.rows()):
    for j in range(vols.columns()):
        vols[i][j] = data[j][i]/100.0

calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
bdc = ql.ModifiedFollowing
daycount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
settlement_days = 2
capfloor_vol = ql.CapFloorTermVolSurface(settlement_days, calendar, bdc, expiries, strikes, vols, daycount)

optionlet_surf = ql.OptionletStripper1(capfloor_vol, ibor_index)
ovs_handle = ql.OptionletVolatilityStructureHandle(
    ql.StrippedOptionletAdapter(optionlet_surf)
)
tenors = np.arange(0,10,0.25)

tenors = np.arange(0,5,0.25)
strike = 0.015
capfloor_vols = [capfloor_vol.volatility(t, strike) for t in tenors]
opionlet_vols = [ovs_handle.volatility(t, strike) for t in tenors]

plt.plot(tenors, capfloor_vols, "--", label="CapFloor Vols")
plt.plot(tenors, opionlet_vols,"-", label="Optionlet Vols")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.25))*
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Github](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/33f1a25078ea79fdd87ac093b677a98bbac90f17/ql/pricingengines/blackformula.cpp), It looks like forward + displacement being > 0 is a requirement of the pricing engine in Quantlib.

```
void checkParameters(QuantLib::Real strike,
                     QuantLib::Real forward,
                     QuantLib::Real displacement)
{
    QL_REQUIRE(displacement >= 0.0, "displacement ("
                                        << displacement
                                        << ") must be non-negative");
    QL_REQUIRE(strike + displacement >= 0.0,
               "strike + displacement (" << strike << " + " << displacement
                                         << ") must be non-negative");
    QL_REQUIRE(forward + displacement > 0.0, "forward + displacement ("
                                                 << forward << " + "
                                                 << displacement
                                                 << ") must be positive");
}
```

In your code 'AddFixing' is called with the exact negative number shown in the error.

```
ibor_index.addFixing(ql.Date(31,1, 2019), -0.368)
```

From my understanding, the numeric portion of 'AddFixing' is an inflation/interest rate. The engine interprets this rate as the 'forward' portion the equation. In most cases I can understand that it should always be positive, but recently with the emergence of negative interest rates I can see why you might intend for it to be negative. If my assumptions are correct, it might be worth contributing to or filing a bug on the QuantLib codebase to allow for negative numbers here.

> Edit: 
>   It appears this is expected behavior and the way to handle negative interest rates is to add displacement. More information can be found on this [thread](http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/Negative-Rates-QuantLib-Python-Cap-Floors-QL-NEGATIVE-RATES-td18453.html). Essentially a negative number cannot be entered into a logarithm. Displacement can be calculated or perhaps can be obtained from quote provider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. if i remove the addFixing I still get the error: RuntimeError: forward + displacement (-0.368 + 0) must be positive.  Is there s way to get a workaround of it?

Comment: What if you put a positive rate in addFixing as a troubleshooting step - to see if it at least runs through the code.

Comment: I think the key here is going to be in a positive displacement number. There are some discussions around negative interest rates and how to deal with them in quantlib. Here for example: http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/negative-interest-rates-td16353.html and http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/Negative-Rates-QuantLib-Python-Cap-Floors-QL-NEGATIVE-RATES-td18453.html This will allow your forward rate to remain negative while correcting the lognormal interest rate model.

Comment: Also, as a side-note, I think that judging from your example link that -0.36% rate should be entered into addFixing as -0.0036.

Comment: Any luck here? If you were able to solve this question another way please post an answer and give it the green check mark.

Comment: No it still gives an error. The same error occurs..

Comment: I've looked at this code for the last couple of hours. Changing the negative number in the addfixing() function _does_ slightly change the number in the error for me, but the error type is still the same. I have tried to modify the displacement number mentioned above, but I'm suspicious that this is not possible to do in the python version of Quantlib. I can't seem to find where it can be added as an arg to the BlackCapFloorPricingEngine. I'm sorry I wasn't able to help more here.